# How to get all the data from form submission in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm working on an online school system, and I am very new to Django.

I have created a student list in my database and from that database, I have given that student data to my template and displayed it in a table.

Now I want to confirm they are present in the class and give that data back to the backend. I have a select option for selecting yes or no.  Then I have a submit button. But after submitting, I only get the data of the last student.

Please explain how to get all the student data to the backend.

My model

```py
class StudentAttendance(models.Model):
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    admission_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    attendance = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    held_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    submit_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.grade
```

My view

```py
@login_required(login_url='login')
def grade8_dashboard(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        grade = request.POST.get("grade","")        
        subject = request.POST.get("subject","")
        admission_number = request.POST.get("admission_number","")      
        first_name = request.POST.get("first_name","")
        last_name = request.POST.get("last_name","")
        attendance = request.POST.get("attendance","")
        # held_date = request.POST.get("held_date","")
        submit_date = request.POST.get("submit_date","")
    
        student = StudentAttendance(grade=grade, subject=subject, admission_number=admission_number, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, attendance=attendance, submit_date=submit_date)
        student.save()
        
    student_details = StudentDetail.objects.all()
        
    context = {
        'student_details' : student_details 
    }
    return render(request, 'grade8-dashbaord.html', context)
```

My template/Form

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Admission No</th>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Present Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for student in student_details %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    <div class="form-group ">

                        <select class="form-control" style="appearance: none;" id="admission_number" name="admission_number">
                            <option>{{student.admission_number}}</option>                                      
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <select class="form-control" style="appearance: none;" id="first_name" name="first_name">
                            <option>{{student.first_name}}</option>                                    
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <select class="form-control" style="appearance: none;" id="last_name" name="last_name">
                            <option>{{student.last_name}}</option>                                     
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control " style="text-align: center;" id="attendance" name="attendance">
                            <option>Yes</option>
                            <option>No</option>           
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="birthdaytime">Grade :</label>
            <select class="form-control" style="appearance: none; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 500;" id="grade" name="grade">
                            <option>{{user.studying_grade}}</option>                                       
                        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="birthdaytime">Subject :</label>
            <select class="form-control" style="appearance: none; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 500;" id="subject" name="subject">
                            <option>{{user.assigned_subject}}</option>                                     
                        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">

        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save each student one by one (django forms approach), or you can submit form with javascript where all your students in a list will be stored as "item" with value like stringified JSON, anfter that you can get all the items as list on your backend with request.POST.getlist("items").

Comment: Hi.  Thank you for reaching out.  As I am not an expert in Javascript, is it possible for you to point me to a relevant tutorial regarding this?  Thank you for the support.

Comment: I couldn't find tutorial for your secific case, you need to generate an array of dictionaries with values from inputs, and then submit them using $.ajax

Comment: hI. Ilyas. Thank your answering to the above question.  I couldnt get it done because I am new.  So I have posted a new question with clarity to the question.  Please be kind enough to look into it and help me with a solution.  The link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69295705/ger-all-form-data-as-a-list-iterate-over-it-and-dilplay-them-in-a-table-on-temp