# Ger all form data as a list, iterate over it and dilplay them in a table on template

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I am working on a simple school project where students and teachers are registered as users.  class monitors get a student list of their class and monitors have to submit and send a report to class teacher that all the students in the class are present for a certain lesson.  So I have created a student model where parent class is the admission number.  Then I have filtered a certain class (ex: Grade-6) and render them in to a template (grade-6 dashboard) and gave access to grade 6 class monitor.  So the monitor can see all the student with their admission number on monitor dashboard.   Then I have insert a select option with each student to select yes or no to say he or she is present or not.  Then submit.   After submitting in my view.py I get all the data as request.POST.  But after saving the form (form.save()) I get last student details only.   But all the details are in request.POST  but I cannot get them to render in to a template.  **I dont know how.**  So I tried getting them as a list or a dict but couldnt.  Please help me on getting this done.

My form in HTML

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Admission No</th>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Present Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for student in student_names %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    <div class="form-group "> 

                        <select class="form-control" style="appearance: none;" id="admission_number" name="admission_number" >
                            <option>{{student.admission_number}}</option>                                      
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <select class="form-control" style="appearance: none;" id="first_name" name="first_name" >
                            <option>{{student.first_name}}</option>                                    
                        </select>
                        
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <select class="form-control" style="appearance: none;" id="last_name" name="last_name" >
                            <option>{{student.last_name}}</option>                                     
                        </select>
                        
                    </div>
                </td> 

                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control " style="text-align: center;" id="attendance" name="attendance">
                            <option>Yes</option>
                            <option>No</option>           
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>       
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>    
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="birthdaytime">Grade :</label>
    <select class="form-control" style="appearance: none; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 500;" id="grade" name="grade" >
                            <option>{{user.studying_grade}}</option>                                       
                        </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label for="birthdaytime">Subject :</label>
<select class="form-control" style="appearance: none; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 500;" id="subject" name="subject" >
                            <option>{{user.assigned_subject}}</option>                                     
                        </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">

</div>`
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

My View

```
def grade8_dashboard(request):

    student_details = Student.objects.all()
    student_names = Student.objects.filter(grade="Grade-6")

    form = StudentAttendanceForm()
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)

        # for i in  request.POST:
        #   a = list(request.POST.items())
        # print(a)
        data = {
            
        }
        return render(request, 'attendance-report.html', data) 

    context = {

        'student_details' : student_details,
        'student_names' : student_names,
        'form' : form,
        
    }
    return render(request, 'grade8-dashbaord.html', context)
```

when I tried printing request.POST I get this

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['De2KjgcFvrhbTzycuCKk6Ay0l394rBCv0aI3LNluhb1YpcfaJq6wZkWBBXU6YRE4'], 'admission_number': ['0002', '0003', '0004'], 'first_name': ['Jon', 'Ruwan', 'Hkee'], 'last_name': ['Doe', 'RED', 'REte'], 'attendance': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes'], 'grade': ['Grade-8'], 'subject': ['MATHS']}>
```

when I tried printing a I get this

```
[('csrfmiddlewaretoken', 'De2KjgcFvrhbTzycuCKk6Ay0l394rBCv0aI3LNluhb1YpcfaJq6wZkWBBXU6YRE4'), ('admission_number', '0004'), ('first_name', 'Hkee'), ('last_name', 'REte'), ('attendance', 'Yes'), ('grade', 'Grade-8'), ('subject', 'MATHS')]
```

I need to get all the details I get when printing request.POST as when I print a and render them in to a template as a table so teachers can view and edit them.

some help is much aprreciated please.

Comment: Don't you wish to store attendance as separate data like (student, lesson, date, attendace) ? Because otherwise you won't be able to calculate attendence days or lessons.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer.  I tried giving request.post.getlist() .  It gave me an empty list.  I tried using admission_number as pram and it gave me a list with admission_number and name. Is this correct. I need to get attendance as well.  How  to get admission_number : 001 ,  name: Jon. attendance: yes.  Thank you very much for the answer

Comment: I'm asking about concept of your idea? What you want to do with data (what kind of reports you want to generate by using this data). For example you want to list students and show their admission at specific date, or maybe at specific lesson. Also according to my experience you will need to store teacher and lesson, to store who has entered this data and for which lesson

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering.  Yes. I need to list students for a specific lesson and show their admission to the teacher for specific date.  You are correct.